# Problems after installing ATI proprietary driver

Tags: drivers, ati, proprietary

I'm an absolute beginner with ubuntu. After installing 11.10 I get a message to install ATI proprietary driver. The new one can't be installed, the older one get installed. After installation I must reboot. I do so and my monitor shows me something like "70Hrz horizontal and 60Hrz vertical are not supported" on a black screen. I don't find a way to set other resolution like 1024x768 or 1280x1024 and I can't see something, even CPU seems to be working.

Comment: I think it's related to the monitor not the card.

Answer (score 2):

From the above forums post, boot to recovery mode and run the following commands

```
apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx-kernel-source
apt-get update
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot and X should work.

You can try to install the proprietary drivers, check to see if your card is supported first

Supported hardware : http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware

Installation guide : http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide

Answer (score -1):

you might want to look at this-

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1235817

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.